Почему если убрать эти строки кода (помечены цифрами 1,2,3), то ответ будет 99, а если оставить то 9009? answ всегда же равно 0
function Check (x)

local check_x = x
local revers_x = 0

while (check_x > 0) do

  revers_x = revers_x * 10
  revers_x = revers_x + math.fmod(check_x, 10)
  check_x = check_x // 10

 end

 return revers_x == x

 end

 local x = 0
 local answ = 0

for i = 99, 1, -1 do

  for j = 99, 1, -1 do

    x = i * j
  if (answ > x) then   <--1
    break              <--2
  end                  <--3
   if (Check(x) == true) then
      answ = x
      break
    end
   end
  end
  print(answ)


Почему вы думаете что "answ всегда же равно 0"?

ну, я так думаю, могу ошибаться, главное почему в одном случае 99, а в другом 9009?

Потому что тот if, который вы отметили, запрещает значению answ уменьшаться. С ним оно может только расти. А если его убрать, то answ может уменьшаться. Перебор x делается в от больших значений к меньшим (в каком-то смысле). Так что с if вы получаете самый большой палиндром, а без него какой-то, возможно меньший.

а если циклы будут не обратными, то мы получил 252, я так понял, что условие натыкается на первый палиндром и завершает программу? Или она завершается как только answ становиться меньше x?

Если if есть, то возвращается самый большой палиндром (и это не зависит от порядка перебора множителей). Если его нет, возвращается какой-то палиндром (и это зависит от порядка перебора множителей). Какой именно не так легко сказать.

Я в lua не понимаю ни грамма, но это вопрос больше о понимании концепции программирования. Сначала вы определяете revers_x = 0. Далее у вас идёт цикл while с условием check_x > 0, которое не выполняется (Думаю, объяснять "почему?" не стоит).
Вот это, на сколько я понимаю, обратные циклы, которые будут идти от 99 до 1 с шагом -1. За каждую итерацию у вас x присваивается значение i * j, т.е., уже на первой итерации x = i * j = 99 * 99 = 9801
Далее идёт проверка, если ваш answ, который в этот момент равен 0, больше произведения i на j, т.е. 9801, что, конечно же, не так. После этого идёт вызов функции Check, которая делает проверку, является ли число палиндромом. Если да, значит результат присваивается в переменную answ.
Самый первый палиндром при таких начальных значениях (99 для i, и 99 для j) является 9009, т.е. когда i = 99, j = 91.
После этого, во всех следующих итерациях будет выполняться проверка if (answ > x), т.е., больше ли уже записанный палиндром произведения при следующих итерациях (Что, конечно же не так, поскольку все следующие палиндромы будут меньше). Если да, значит действие цикла прекращается, и управление кодом не доходит до строчки if (Check(x) == true).
Если эту проверку просто убрать, значит вы будете каждый раз опять проверять, является ли число палиндромом, и если это так, вы будете обновлять переменную answ до того момента, пока она не станет равная 1

"(Что, конечно же не так, поскольку все следующие палиндромы будут меньше)" - сильное утверждение. Вообще говоря, x перебираются не по убыванию.

"вы будете обновлять переменную answ до того момента, пока она не станет равная 1" - это не правда. Там ещё один break есть.

@StanislavVolodarskiy, два ваших комментария не верны вообще. Как минимум, я зашёл в интернет и прочитал как работаю такие циклы и каких из циклов прерывает break. Есть ли палиндромы больше 9009, при произведении числе меньше 99 и 91? Это интересно...

Второй комментарий верен - онлайн компилятор lua печатает 99 без if. Что больше чем единица. Верность первого комментария зависит от верхней границы. Для некоторых границ первый палиндром не является максимальным. Для границы 99 первый палиндром действительно максимальный (что нуждается в доказательстве или проверке). А для границы 89 первый палиндром 979, а за ним следует 6776.
